# Jquery helper function with checkbox foreach

Tags: jquery, checkbox, foreach

I have a few checkboxes that I am trying to get the values from using a jquery helper function.

```
<div class="checkbox">
<label>
<input name="gift_wrap" value="Wrap" type="checkbox"> Gift wrap
</label>
<label>
<input name="gift_wrap" value="Wrapper" type="checkbox"> Wrapper
</label>
<label>
<input name="gift_wrap" value="Pap" type="checkbox"> Pap
</label>
</div>
```

Here's the Jquery:

```
_getContent: function (elm) {
        if(elm.is(":checkbox, :radio")){
            return elm.is(":checked") ? elm.map(function(){
            return $(this).val()}) : '';
        } else {
            return elm.text();
        }
        return '';
    }
```

This is how it's being called:

```
_getProductDetails: function (elm) {
        var mi = this;
        var p = {};
        elm.parents(this.options.productContainerSelector)
            .find(this.options.productElementSelector)
            .each(function() {
                if ($(this).is('[name]') === true || typeof $(this).data('name') !== typeof undefined) {
                    var key = $(this).attr('name') ? $(this).attr('name') : $(this).data('name'); 
                    var val = mi._getContent($(this));
                    if(key && val){
                        p[key] = val;    
                    }
                }
            });
        return p;
    }
```

I am getting this `[object Object]` instead of the values. I am not so good at Jquery and not entirely sure how to go about it, I have also tried `.each` without much success.

Comment: so you're trying to say if a checkbox is checked, return the value?

Comment: How are you calling the helper?

Comment: @Barmar it appended using {gift_wrap}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `.map()` method returns a jQuery collection of the results of the function, not an array. You can use `.get()` to convert it to an array.

But there doesn't seem to be a reason to call `.map()` in the first place. Just return the value of the element if it's checked.

```
_getContent: function (elm) {
    if(elm.is(":checkbox, :radio")){
        return elm.is(":checked") ? elm.val() : '';
    } else {
        return elm.text();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well this is what I started with however it only retrieves just one value. Perhaps I need a foreach somewhere to print {gift_wrap}?

Comment: That's why I asked how you're calling the function. What is the value of `elm`?

Comment: My code should work. You have a `.each()` loop in `_getProductDetails()`, so `elm` will just be a single checkbox when it calls `_getContent()`. There's only one value to retrieve.

Comment: How can I modify it to get multiple instead on just the single one?

Comment: Isn't that what the `.each()` loop in `_getProductDetails()` does? It puts each element's value in a different property in `p`.

Comment: Ah ok! I renamed the checkboxes and now retrieving each one's value. Although this is fine, anyway to get multiple as an array to avoid naming uniquely?

Comment: Why are you using the same name? That only makes sense for radio buttons, because the name is used to group them. If they're different checkboxes, they should have different names.

Comment: You could make `p[key]` an array. Then do `p[key].push(val)` instead of `p[key] = val`

Comment: Appreciate your advice and time, bit too advance for at this stage. i will have to read up a bit more before I attempt to change it. Will accept your answer though as it solves my problem albeit a different way!

Answer (score 0):

`.map` is a function to be called on an array. I will assume you are passing through a single input. This will work (modified to make it work in snippet)

Also, the last return will never fire. so here's a solution:

```js
_getContent=  function (elm) {
        if(elm.is(":checkbox, :radio")){
            return elm.is(":checked") ? elm.val() : '';
        } 
        return elm.text();
       
    }
    
    console.log(_getContent($('input').eq(1)))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
<label>
<input name="gift_wrap" value="Wrap" type="checkbox"> Gift wrap
</label>
<label>
<input name="gift_wrap" value="Wrapper" type="checkbox" checked> Wrapper
</label>
<label>
<input name="gift_wrap" value="Pap" type="checkbox"> Pap
</label>
</div>
```